# how to compare dates on different linux nodes

Tags: bash, date, ssh

From a Node i want to compare date and then display the difference in hours/days.
An application command say appcmddate displays date at second line, I am taking out the valid format to calculate the epoch and then to compare.

This command works fine on host
linux1~# date --date "`appcmddate| sed -n 2p | cut -d \  -f 3,4,5,6,8`" +%s
1364927572

but it didnt work when I try it over ssh.

```
ssh $node "date --date "appcmddate | sed -n 2p | cut -d \  -f 3,4,5,6,8" +%s"
```

Is there any way to get it work over ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape all *strange* characters:

```
ssh $node "date --date \"appcmddate \| sed -n 2p \| cut -d \\ -f 3,4,5,6,8\" +%s"
```

otherwise, quotes `"`, pipes `|` will be interpreted as on the same level as `ssh` and will pipe `ssh ... | sed | ...`, while you want it to be `ssh (... | ...)`.

Comment: I tried above, it failed, then i tried not escaping pipes.. and it worked to expectation. Your answer helped. Thanks Fedorqui.

Comment: It sounds extrange. So at the end, which exact command worked?

Comment: ssh $node "date --date \"`appcmddate | sed -n 2p | cut -d \\  -f 3,4,5,6,8`\" +%s"